# Using Git to Mirror and Avoid Conflicts

Tags: git, copy

We are currently working on a three-tiered form of development in our department.  Developers work on their local machines pushing and pulling from a centralized virtual machine hosting a bare repo.  After a development cycle is complete we have a deployment server which is the server that is actually used to host the application and our intention is to push/pull to that final deployment server with git, updating database information as well with a post-receive hook.

My understanding is that if the development cycle is long or complex on a there would likely be a number of conflicts between the state of the development server and the deployment server, most of which would have been resolved already during the development process between the local machines and the development server.

Is there a way to easily basically copy the repository and the files from the development to the deployment without a complete mess arising due to these potential conflicts?  One option would be to not use Git at all for this part of the process and simply copy the directories and update the database manually, but something about this method doesn't scream best practice to me.

Comment: I'm not sure why there would "likely be a number of conflicts between the state of the development server and the deployment server". If you never actually modify and commit files on the *deployment server* (which I wouldn't expect you would do), then there should be no reason to expect any conflicts.

Comment: Hi Greg, this makes sense.  Perhaps I'm overthinking it, but I'm seeing the development server holding an updated version of the website and there being conflicts between that updated version and the current pre-updated version on the deployment server, and whatever conflicts that arise needing to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> most of which would have been resolved already during the development process between the local machines and the development server.

Actually, *all* conflicts should be resolved locally before being pushed back: you do that by regular `git pull --rebase`, which replays your local commits on top of the updated upstream branch, making sure your own commits don't have any conflicts before pushing back.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not conflicts are resolved locally, the question is about after all of the conflicts are resolved locally and pushed to the development server - that there may be conflicts/discrepancies between the development and the current state of the deployment server.

Comment: @user4333011 do you know what kind of difference you see on the deployment server compared to the branch initially pushed?

Comment: Not at this time, this is an attempt to avoid problems before they occur.  On any given day the development server may have updated pages, edits etc. that would not yet be on the deployment server.  For instance, a developer makes a lot of changes on their local machine of index.php, they resolve all the conflicts and push the change to the development server, and then there is a discrepancy between the index.php on the development server and the index.php on the deployment server.  I don't want to pull those changes to the deployment server and need to resolve the conflicts again.

Comment: @user4333011: I think you're inventing a problem that (a) you don't actually have, and (b) won't actually occur. The way Git works, there will be no second set of conflicts on the deployment server, if you intend to do what you describe.